# Get previous and current window width

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize

I'm trying to get previous and current window width via JS. I use jQuery for capturing window resize event. Here's my code:

```
<script>
 function getWindowWidth() {
   var myWidth = 0, myHeight = 0;
     if( typeof( window.innerWidth ) == 'number' ) {
         myWidth = window.innerWidth; myHeight = window.innerHeight;
     } else if( document.documentElement && ( document.documentElement.clientWidth ||document.documentElement.clientHeight ) ) {
         myWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth; myHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
     } else if( document.body && ( document.body.clientWidth || document.body.clientHeight ) ) {
         myWidth = document.body.clientWidth; myHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
     }
     return myWidth;
 }
 var lastWindowWidth;
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $(window).resize(function() {
       $('#h1_text').text("Previous: "+ lastWindowWidth + " Current: " + getWindowWidth());
       lastWindowWidth = getWindowWidth();
     });
 });
</script>
```

It returns me:

```
Previous: 1685 Current: 1685
```

Why both Previous: and Current: values are similar? Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/pKfSN/ - I get different values here. Incidentally, you don't need to wrap your resize handler inside `$(document).ready`.

Comment: For me, the values are different if I resize using the edge of the window, but they are the same if I maximize or restore the window. Tested in Chrome

Comment: Heh, still cant get why on my local machine it doesn't work... However, look what I've noticed: "Previous: 647 Current: 663" Is it normal? I need to catch the moment, when window is resized from 980 to 979...

Comment: Oh, I see, still having the same problem as yesterday... didn't you say you just needed to know the first time the width was less than 980? Couldn't you just test the current size and set a flag when it meets the criteria?

Comment: Yeah, you're right (: Still can't manage with this problem. Let me try your solution...

Comment: made a quick edit to mine, basically just set a flag if the window is less than 980 on page load or on a resize event.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You **are** using jQuery.

So use jQuery:

```
$(window).width();
```

---

```
 var lastWindowWidth;
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $(window).resize(function() {
       var $window = $(this),
           windowWidth = $window.width();
       $('#h1_text').text("Previous: "+ lastWindowWidth + " Current: " + windowWidth );
       lastWindowWidth = windowWidth;
     });
 });
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/pKfSN/5/

Comment: Thanks! AS the previous solution, it also sometimes returns me "Previous: 601 Current: 582". Dont know how to deal with this) I just need to catch the moment, when window is resized from 980 to 979

Comment: I've checked on Chrome 21.0.1180.82 on MacOS

Comment: you can't control what values are returned.  You can track when the window is resized, and the new values but that's it.  If they go from maximized to half screen, or they resize it down by 1000 pixels, you are still only going to get the new values, whatever they are.

Comment: @Neal: You may try to resize the window quickly - when it's resized slowly, it works fine

Comment: @Ilya - by "I just need to catch the moment, when window is resized from 980 to 979" are you saying you want to catch the very moment _during the resize drag_ that the window width drops below 980px?

Answer (score 2):

The essence of the answer is to capture the `previous_window_width` before the window is resized:

```
var previous_window_width = $(window).width();

...

$(window).resize(function() {
    var current_window_width = $(window).width();
    // do whatever you need with previous_window_width
});
```

Answer (score 0):

here you go http://jsfiddle.net/B9chY/

```
var lastWindowWidth = $(window).width();

$(window).resize(function() {
   $('#h1_text').text("Previous: "+ lastWindowWidth + " Current: " + $(window).width());
       lastWindowWidth = $(window).width();
 });
```

based on comments:

```
var lessThan = false;

$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 980) {
        lessThan = true;
    }
});

$(window).resize(function() {
   if ($(window).width() < 980) {
        lessThan = true;
    }
});
```